# How to get nuget restore in TFS build

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

I can't make it work TFS build. It is nuget restore issue. Nuget is not restoring reference dll files.

Here is belwo my build configuration. Please advise me how I can make this works.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As per [this blog post](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build) on Nuget's website you can use the command line you mentioned, but it has to be part of a custom target using a `Build.proj` file.

You need to add a `Build.proj` and put this as the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         DefaultTargets="Build"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutDir Condition=" '$(OutDir)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\</OutDir>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='' ">Release</Configuration>
    <SourceHome Condition=" '$(SourceHome)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)src\</SourceHome>
    <ToolsHome Condition=" '$(ToolsHome)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)tools\</ToolsHome>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Solution Include="$(SourceHome)*.sln">
      <AdditionalProperties>OutDir=$(OutDir);Configuration=$(Configuration)</AdditionalProperties>
    </Solution>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="RestorePackages">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ToolsHome)NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;%(Solution.Identity)&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Clean">
    <MSBuild Targets="Clean"
             Projects="@(Solution)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
    <MSBuild Targets="Build"
             Projects="@(Solution)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
    <MSBuild Targets="Rebuild"
             Projects="@(Solution)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Alternatively, you could call it from a [custom Pre-Build Script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353.aspx).

Or, [customise the XAML template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx) and add a Foreach loop to invoke:

```
nuget.exe restore path\to\solution.sln
```

on each solution in the build definition.

Comment: I received this error - "The command C:\OrderProcessEngine\tools\Nuget\nuget.exe "restore "" exited with code 1.

Comment: I've googled that and most people suggest setting the build verbosity to Diagnostic and checking what else is happening.

Comment: Dave, what do you mean by build project? What project type is this? I don't see this in VS templates or online templates

Comment: You can just create a file called Build.proj with the Above content in it. Then edit it to have your solution file in it.

Comment: @RandallTo, please check my reply for the steps.  +1 for Dave's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps (described [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build) which was mentioned in Dave's post) you need to follow in order to have these NuGet packages restored during the VSO (TFS) build process.

1. Add following items to the solution. (Content of the nuget.config and .tfignore file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))

[image]

2. Add one build.proj file under the root path of the solution folder. (Content of the build.proj file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))
3. Create one folder named **tools** under the root path of the solution folder. Create **NuGet** sub-folder under **tools** folder, download and save [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/nuget.exe) under tools\NuGet path.
4. Check in **nuget.config**, **.tfignore**, **build.proj** and **tools\NuGet\nuget.exe** into TFS version control.
5. Modify the build definition to choose to build the build.proj file.
   [image]

Then you will have NuGet packages restored successfully during the TFS build process.